# Magento - Resize images, keep aspect ratio, crop what exceeds the size

Tags: php, image, magento, crop, aspect-ratio

I want to resize an image in magento keeping its aspect ratio and make it fill a rectangle with another aspect ratio.

Example:

My image is 640x480

And my rectangle is 100x50

I want the image to fill ALL the rectangle and crop what exceeds it.

I'm aware of *keepFrame(FALSE)* - It doesn't make the image fill the rectangle, instead it makes it fit inside and doesnt crop anything.

Also, if you familiar with Wordpress, what I want is the as doing:
*add_image_size('home',370,256,true);*

Thank you :)

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/47269/

Comment: I was hoping to do it with the builtin functionality. but that does the job. thanks @R.S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look @

Since magento has change there page link structure try http://web.archive.org/web/20140707042130/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/47269/

<strike>[Crop product thumbnail images to clean square](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/47269/)</strike>

Try

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(120,null); ?>" width="120" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
```

Comment: While this answer is over a year old and the link is helpful it would be better if you post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: This is now 3 yr old answer.